# MapView menu item crashing when loading attempting to load map

Tags: java, android, maps

My app is crashing when the map item is selected from my menu.  I think I am doing one of two things (if not both) wrong.  1 - In my menu switch statement I'm not calling the new activity (map) correctly. 2 - My map activity isn't configured correctly.

FriendsApp.java (I excluded unnecessary bits):

```
public class FriendApp extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */


 WebView mWebView;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://example.com/myfrienddash.php");

    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new FriendWebViewClient());
}

//Tell main menu what to do when elements are clicked
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case FRIENDS:
     mWebView.loadUrl("http://example.com/myfrienddash2.php");
        return true;
    case MAP:
        Intent friendMap = new Intent(FriendApp.this, FriendMaps.class);
        startActivity(friendMap);
        return true;
    case SEARCH:
     mWebView.loadUrl("http://example.com/myfrienddash3.php");
     return true;
    case INFO:
     mWebView.loadUrl("http://example.com/myfrienddash4.php");
     return true;
    case QUIT:
     finish();
     return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}}
```

FriendMaps.java:

```
public class FriendMaps extends MapActivity {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mapview);

    MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

    List<Overlay> mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.androidmarker);
    BuoyItemizedOverlay itemizedoverlay = new BuoyItemizedOverlay(drawable, mapView.getContext());

    double longitude = 44.5;
    double latitude = -63.4;

 GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(longitude * 1E6), 
   (int)(latitude * 1E6));
 OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(point, "what you talking aboot", "eh!");

 itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);
}

 //Not using route feature so return false (must be set)
 @Override
 protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return false;
 }
 }
```

I am currently just statically adding some coordinates to get it working.

Any help is appreciated.

Added Manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.company.friendapp"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:name=".FriendApp"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    </application>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <activity android:name=".FriendMaps" android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />

</manifest>
```

Comment: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the DDMS perspective in Eclipse to examine the stack trace associated with your "crash".

Comment: @CommonsWare - OK thanks, will do that now.  So how I do my Intent friendMap = new Intent(FriendApp.this, FriendMaps.class); is the correct way to Intent?

Comment: There is nothing obviously wrong with that `Intent`. Make sure the activity is registered in your manifest.

Comment: @CommonsWare - log cat is yelling at me! Fatal Exception: main, then next line is: ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find (..) - but I *think* my manifest is correct, I added it above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `<activity>` element needs to be inside your `<application>` element.